# How to insert a scrollview container in canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a scrollview container inside a canvas. Please note I do NOT want the entire canvas to scroll, only a subview i.e. a Menu would scroll on the canvas.

I thought of using the `canvas.clip()` method to create a mask and move the underlying entities based on the scroll position but the `clip()` method hides all other entities of the canvas. Any way of selecting what would be clipped?

Any ideas how to go about this? Is it possible?

Comment: _"entities of the canvas"_? the canvas has no such concept as "entities". It's just plain old pixels. the easiest thing to do would be to overlay a HTML DOM element containing the menu over your canvas element.

Comment: oops, I guess I carried over some terminology from the impactjs game engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Superimpose *a second canvas* over the top of your original canvas and use CSS z-index to sort out which one is on top of the other. Then just use the clip method on the scroll view canvas.

```
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="canvas"         width="800" height="500"></canvas>
    <canvas id="scroll-view"    width="800" height="500"></canvas>
</div>

div
{
    position:relative;
    width:800px;
    height:500px;
}
canvas
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    display:block;
    width:800px;
    height:500px;
}
#canvas
{
    z-index:1;
}
#scroll-view
{
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I can layover the zynga canvas scroller on top of my own canvas.
[zynga canvas scroller](https://github.com/zynga/scroller)
Although @Cerbrus idea of laying over DOM elements tends to be less complicated unless you need the canvas